# Evento onchange não funcionando quando colocado no body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Escrevi esta função para validar alguns radio buttons específicos do formulário. Como minha página é em PHP e faço includes do topo e rodapé, a função funciona quando está no footer.php, mas como a função não se aplica a todas as páginas, tenho que colocar individualmente no body das páginas específicas. Quando faço isso misteriosamente não funciona e não reporta erros no console.

```
$(function(){

    $('body').on( 'change', ':radio', function(){
        if( $('input[value="3"]:checked').length > 5 ){
             alert('Somente 5 opções críticas podem ser marcadas');
            $(this).prop({ checked : false });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Funciona para mim. Pode postar o seu HTML? __http://jsfiddle.net/WSbE5/__ Atenção que este selector só procura inputs com `value="3"`

Comment: Quando colocas no `BODY` estás a carregar o jQuery antes desse código ser lido? Ou só carregas o jQuery no fim da página? Recebes algum erro na consola do navegador?

Comment: rapaz, meu HTML tem 2000+ linhas. =p

Comment: @Zuul Sim, o jQuery está no header.php, ou seja, no topo entre o `<head></head>`

Comment: @LeandroRuel, as tuas checkboxes têm no HTML `value="3"` ? Tens um link?

Comment: E relativo ao que o Sergio perguntou sobre a limitação que o teu código tem de só trabalhar com `input` cujo valor seja 3? Apercebeste-te dessa particularidade? Ps: podes fazer um [teste deste género](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/WSbE5/1/) para saber se o código funciona mas não faz _match_ com os teus elementos.

Comment: @Zuul descobri que era isso mesmo, o value do formulário estava diferente, como o formulário é super grande, estava sendo dificil procurar todos inputs, ele estava com value "a|3", agora já arrumei aqui.

Comment: @Sergio Responde dando conta do problema para o Leandro Ruel poder fechar este assunto. E Leandro nada como um bom teste ;)

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é demasiado localizada

Comment: @Zuul foi um equívoco.

Comment: @LeandroRuel É um [**problema bem comum**](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BCh-v51CAAA9HuT.jpg) a todos os programadores e acontece a todos :)

Answer (score 1):

O problema aqui parece ser o HTML não ter o que o selector estava à procura.

Quando fazes uso de:

```
 $('input[value="3"]:checked')
```

Estás a dizer para serem localizados elementos do tipo `input` cujo valor presente no atributo `value` seja igual a `3` e cujo seu estado seja `checked`.

Como podes ver [neste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/WSbE5/), o código funciona. Por outro lado podes fazer uso [deste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/WSbE5/1/) para averiguar se no teu ambiente o código efectivamente está a ser utilizador mas sem encontrar resultados com o selector que aplicaste.

---

Mediante o teu comentário:

> @Zuul descobri que era isso mesmo, o value do formulário estava diferente, como o formulário é super grande, estava sendo dificil procurar todos inputs, ele estava com value "a|3", agora já arrumei aqui. – Leandro Ruel

Sabemos que o teu selector procurava `value="3"` e o HTML tinha `value="a|3"`, tornando assim está pergunta "Demasiado Localizada" por se tratar de um *typo* que dificilmente vai ajudar alguém no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

você colocou os seus scripts dentro de alguma função de verificação de carregamento?

Pelo que você disse, só funciona quando coloca no rodapé, após a página carregar.

Tente com o document.ready, assim ele verifica se todo DOM foi carregado antes de aplicar a função.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on( 'change', ':radio', function(){
        if( $('input[value="3"]:checked').length > 5 ){
             alert('Somente 5 opções críticas podem ser marcadas');
             $(this).prop({ checked : false });
        }
    });

});
```